# How to get only specific fields of data from firestore

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get all the brand names of gas stations in my database and display those names in React component, but I am not sure what query should I use and how I am supposed to store this data.

I have already tried to get the needed information from Firestore and to store it into redux, but it is not working. Should I use separate reducers?

```
export const setStations = stations => ({
  type: actionTypes.SET_STATIONS,
  stations
});

export const setStationsNames = stationsNames => ({
  type: actionTypes.SET_STATIONS_NAMES,
  stationsNames
});

export const startSetStations = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return db
      .collection('stations')
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        const stations = [];
        const stationsNames = [];
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
          stations.push(doc.data());
          stationsNames.push(doc.data().brand);
        });
        dispatch(setStationsNames(stationsNames));
        dispatch(setStations(stations));
      });
  };
};
```

```
{props.stations.map((station, i) => {
  return (
    <li key={i} className="station">
      <h3 className="station__text">{station.brand}</h3>
     </li>
  );
})}
```

Reducer

```
export default (state = stationsReducerDefaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.SET_STATIONS:
      return action.stations;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

[My firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5A04.png)

Comment: How does your reducer look like and do you get any error?

Comment: @Clarity I do not get any errors. My reducer is really simple one. I wasnt sure how to setup it, so that's why I asked this question. 
`export default (state = stationsReducerDefaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.SET_STATIONS:
      return action.stations;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};`

Comment: Could you add it to the question? Also your initial state. The code looks ok so far, so maybe you're just not getting the data from the db?

Comment: I added reducer to the question. My initial state from the reducer is just an empty array. All I need is to fetch the brands from all stations and display it to the component. Maybe I should create a separate reducer just for this and store it this way?

Comment: But can you verify if you get any data from the firestore? I think it'd be `snapshot.forEach` and not `snapshot.docs.forEach`.

Comment: I can get data from the firestore. I also attached a photo of my db to the post. The point is, I need only the brand names of all stations in one array or any sort of variable. Is it possible to fetch all the brand names, push it into an array and store in a Redux state with all other information of stations (the same brand and address)? Or should I create a separate reducer for it?

Comment: Your station data already contains brand names, why do you need to store brand names separately?

Comment: Ahh, yeah, you are right. I don't know why I wanted to store it into a separate container. Thanks!